# multiple upload Jquery & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been looking for code for multiple ajax images Upload (PHP/Jquery/mysql), and I found this , and I like it.
But I want to somebody help me to make it uploading 3 images only.

http://www.9lessons.info/2013/09/multiple-ajax-image-upload-jquery.html

**Can you help , please?**

Comment: Put a condition man..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just maintain a count of how many images are uploaded and stop it after the max limit you want. Like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
      var maxImageToUpload = 3;
      var totalImagesUploaded = 0;
      $('#photoimg').on('change', function() 
      {
        if(totalImagesUploaded < maxImageToUpload ){ // check if 3 are uploaded and stop if so..
          var A=$("#imageloadstatus");
          var B=$("#imageloadbutton");

          $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview', 
            beforeSubmit:function(){
             A.show();
             B.hide();
             }, 
           success:function(){
               A.hide();
               B.show();
               totalImagesUploaded++; // increment the count for every successful upload of image.
             }, 
           error:function(){
              A.hide();
              B.show();
             } }).submit();
         }
        });
});
```